# ./configure command not found while configuring gearman php extension in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, gearman

I've downloaded the latest version of gearman php extension from gearmean website, but
when i tried to configure gearman phpextension, i'm  getting the error configure command not found. When i go through the gearman folder also i did not find the configure file in that. I'm getting the following error while running the ./configure command in the line.

Before that i've installed gearman server successfully and running the gearman server.

Can any one help me out from this?

Comment: You can't run the configure script if the script is not present. I suggest rereading the installation instructions and making sure you've got the correct source distribution and so on.

Comment: I've gone through the installation instructions before i'm trying to run this script, they are all running the system successfully. I've downloaded from the gearman website for latest version.

Comment: But if the configure script is not there then you can't run it. Are you sure you downloaded the correct version and so on.
Also check if you should run [autoconf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf) instead to generate the configure script (hint: look for `configure.ac`).

Comment: Thank you for your suggession. I've checked in other versions also, but i could not found the configure file as you said (configure.ac) is also not available. But the files configure and configure.ac files are available on gearman server. Any way to get install the files.

Answer (score 1):

When we run the phpize in the command prompt then the configuration file will be automatically created. Then we can run the command ./configure and make command to install the gearman php extension. Finally i found the solution